# Android: Gradle generateDebugSources issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ubuntu-15.04

I am running **Android Studio 2.2** on **Ubuntu 15.04**. Whenever "***generateDebugSources***" runs it complains that the machine doesnt contain Mac Android SDK libraries. 

This is the error I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
The SDK directory '/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

This is the corresponding stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The SDK directory '/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk' does not exist.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.getSdkLoader(SdkHandler.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:86)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:673)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:610)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
```

**ANDROID_HOME** and **JAVA_HOME** env variables are set as expected.

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

I am not sure why it is looking for Mac SDK on ubuntu machine.

Comment: double check your `local.properties` file. the `sdk.dir` might be set there

Answer (score 0):

Try these suggestions:

1) Check if the sdk folder has permissions

2)

a - Right click your project and select 'Open Module Settings' under SDK Location put your location for your SDK.

b - Paste in '/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk'

c - Clean and rebuild your project

3)

a - Try to delete your local.properties file and create a new one, but don't check it into version control.

b - Right click top level of project and Create new file 'local.properties' then add: '/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk'

c - Clean and Build